undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.element.contactName') react.js project error
hello I have this code its a simple project for adding contacts in react js my problem is the I get the following error when I am trying to add a new contact
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.element.contactName')
import React from "react";

class AddContact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      errorMessage: undefined,
      successMessage: undefined,
    };
  }

  handleAddContactFromSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = e.target.element.contactName.value.trim();
    const email = e.target.element.contactEmail.value.trim();
    const phone = e.target.element.contactPhone.value.trim();
    this.props.handleAddContact({ name: name, email: email, phone: phone });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="border col-12 text-white p-2">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAddContactFromSubmit}>
          <div className="row p-2">
            <div className="col-12 text-white-50">Add a new Contact</div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-4 p-1">
              <input
                className="from-control form-control-sm"
                placeholder="Name..."
                name="contactName"
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-4 p-1">
              <input
                className="from-control form-control-sm"
                placeholder="Email..."
                name="contactEmail"
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-4 p-1">
              <input
                className="from-control form-control-sm"
                placeholder="Phone..."
                name="contactPhone"
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-6 offset-md-3 p-1">
              <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm form-control ">
                Create
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AddContact;



The "target" property of an event is a reference to a DOM element. e.target.element is wrong; just e.target. Your code should verify that e.target is referring to the <form> element also.

You need to use elements not element
So for example:
const name = e.target.elements.contactName.value.trim();
And some optimisations :) :
    handleAddContactFromSubmit = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const getValue = (name) => e.target.elements[name].value.trim();
        this.props.handleAddContact({ name: getValue('contactName'), email: getValue('contactEmail'), phone: getValue('contactPhone') });
    };

